# What can I put in a .SVC file for IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to find a definition of the directives that can be put into the file, but can't find any particular reference?

I know of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967389.aspx

which specified @ServiceHost

but you can also use @Assembly etc...   But I can't find a definitive reference of  what .svc is and what you can put in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer intellisense for the `.svc` endpoint file only shows `@ServiceHost` and `@Assembly` so that's pretty much your lot.

You would use the `@Assembly` attribute to reference to other source files or assemblies if you were in-lining your WCF endpoint code in the `.svc` file instead of in a codebehind file.

Comment: thats what I have, I've got a library containing my WCF services and I've created a WCF web app to host the services.  I was trying to work out how to run some initial start up code in the web app host.